# Laravel seeder column json

Tags: laravel

I am creating a seeder in laravel, but I have to write 1 column json data, but I could not do it, how can I create a seeder column.

Seeder `In seeder there will be "bank name" and "iban" in iban column`

[image]
Migration

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('account_type');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->json('ibans')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Seeder

```
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('settings')->insert([
            'name' => 'Şirket Ünvanı',
            'account_type' => 'settings',
            'ibans' => json_decode('"a":1,"b":2',true),
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now(),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: yes she made a very different recording from that

Comment: hasan senin laravel bilgin varmı ?

Comment: @lidersin that looks strange:  'name' => 'Şirket Ünvanı',

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('settings')->insert([
            'name' => 'Şirket Ünvanı',
            'account_type' => 'settings',
            'ibans' => json_encode(['bankname' => 1, 'iban' => '2', '0' => true]),
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now(),
        ]);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: mysql column `{"bankname":1,"iban":"2","0":true}`

Comment: ? Just put it in the array.  json_encode(['bankname' => 1, 'iban' => '2', '0' => true])

Comment: `ibans: "[{\"bankname\":1,\"iban\":\"2\"}]"` It does not come as an array in json format. the recording i made

Comment: I added the image to the topic.

Comment: There is an error in the spelling of seeder "iban", the model has a cast

Answer (score 0):

You can add this json field to your Model (Settings) as casting field `(protected $cast)`. It will be automatically handles json_encode, -decode to an array.

```
protected $casts = [
    'ibans' => 'array'
];

$settings->ibans = $array; 
$array = $settings->ibans;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: I didn't understand what you said, I want it to write `[{"bankname":"aaa","iban":"TR111"}]` in seeder

Comment: I am getting error while running seeder

Comment: I added the image to the topic.

Comment: @lidersin  1. Your iban array has a mistake. 2. you add the protected $cast var with the ibans field to you settingsmodel?

Comment: There is a typo can you check?

Comment: @lidersin `["":"123","b":"256]` is wrong. sorry was my mistake. if you like to pass a json object then you pass a string. '["a":"123","b":"256"]' . In suggested you to add this field  to the cast var in your model. then you have pass only a array like `["a"=>"123", "b"=>"456"]`

Comment: ` Array to string conversion`  I added the new image.